# How to group by a multikey dict in Python by one key?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a multikey dict here. I am trying to group by the dict by a the first key (A, B) and convert it to a transposed dataframe and write it to a csv file.

```
>>> dic= { ('A',1): 4, ('A',1):2, ('B', 1): 2, ('A', 2): 5, ('B', 2):3}
>>> dic
{('A', 1): 2, ('B', 1): 2, ('A', 2): 5, ('B', 2): 3}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dic.items()).groupby(0).sum()
>>> df
        1
0
(A, 1)  2
(A, 2)  5
(B, 1)  2
(B, 2)  3
```

here is what I have been doing so far:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(dic.items()).groupby(0).sum()
>>> df
        1
0
(A, 1)  4
(A, 2)  5
(B, 1)  2
(B, 2)  3

>>> df_t = df.T
0  (A, 1)  (A, 2)  (B, 1)  (B, 2)
1       4       5       2       3
>>> df_t.to_csv(./file.csv)
```

What I am looking to get is something like this:

```
    1     2
A   6     5
B   2     3
```

Comment: as dictionaries contain key-value pairs, the dic you are referring to contain non unique keys i.e `('A',1): 4, ('A',1):2` so it would be evaluated as  `('A',1):2` while processing (point is Dictionaries do not support duplicate keys). the output you want can be achieved using [pivot_table](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) however first you have to deal with the dic and get all of your values by treating duplication of keys.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a dictionary never contains duplicated keys (i.e A dictionary can hold 1 key to N values, but not N keys to 1 value). In current scenario your `dic` contain duplicate keys so while executing it will take most recent value only. If your `dic` contain duplicate keys possible solution is to put the values inside lists. Something like

```
dic = { ('A',1): 4, ('A',1):2, ('B', 1): 2, ('A', 2): 5, ('B', 2):3}
```

should be,

```
dic = {('A',1):[4,2], ('B', 1): [2], ('A', 2): [5], ('B', 2):[3]}
```

Now the solution part,

```
import pandas as pd

#data
dic = {('A',1):[4,2], ('B', 1): [2], ('A', 2): [5], ('B', 2):[3]}

#Converting dic to dataframe object
df = pd.DataFrame(dic.items())

#Explode will convert list of values to row like structure 
exp = df[1].explode().to_frame().reset_index()

#Merging df and exp to combine results
df = df.reset_index().merge(exp, on = 'index', how = 'left')

#Converting tuple of keys into separate columns
df[['i1','i2']] = df[0].apply(pd.Series)

#Summing up the result and then pivoting them to get desired result
df.groupby(['i1','i2'])['1_y'].sum().reset_index().pivot(index=['i1'],columns=['i2'],values=['1_y'])

#Renaming columns and index
res.columns = ['1','2']
res.index.names = ['']
res
```

Output:

```
      1 2
    
A     6 5
B     2 3
```